# Magento output category and subcategories in alphabetical order

Tags: php, magento

I have the code to output a category in magento by ID, but want these results to be output in alphabetical order. Can anyone suggest anything?

```
 <?php 
$parentCategoryId = 201;
$cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentCategoryId);
$subcats = $cat->getChildren();

// Get 1 Level sub category of Parent category
foreach(explode(',',$subcats) as $subCatid)
              {
                $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($subCatid);
  if($_category->getIsActive()) {
     echo '<li><a href="'.$_category->getURL().'" title="View the products for the "'.$_category->getName().'" category">'.$_category->getName().'</a>';
   echo '</li>';
  }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the below code:

```
 <?php 
    $parentCategoryId = 201;

    Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('parent_id',$parentCategoryId)->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Happy Coding...